# Integration ambiguity

Tags: integration, rational-functions

I am trying to Evaluate $$I=\int\frac{x^4+1}{x^6+1}dx$$ Now $I$ can be written as

$$I=\int\frac{x^4(1+\frac{1}{x^4})}{x^6(1+\frac{1}{x^6})}dx=\int\frac{(1+\frac{1}{x^4})}{x^2(1+\frac{1}{x^6})}dx$$

Now i used the Substitution $$\frac{1}{x}=t$$ $\implies$ $\frac{dx}{x^2}=-dt$

So $I$ becomes

$$I=-\int\frac{1+t^4}{1+t^6}dt$$ and Since $t$ is dummy variable we have

$$I=-I$$ so $$I=0$$ I could not find where is the flaw in my solution.

Comment: To understand what happens, first try the same argument with $\int {1\over 1+t^2}$. Perhaps, you might want first to write down the bounds of the integral fos intsnace $\int _1^x$, and notice thta $1/x$ would change there order ?

Comment: **Hint:** Add and subtract $x^2$ in the numerator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The step where you conclude $I=-I$ is invalid.

Suppose $\int\frac{x^4+1}{x^6+1}dx=f(x)$

Then you can only conclude $f(x)=-f(t)$ which implies $f(x)=-f({1\over x})$ and indeed $f(1)=f(-1)=0$ but you cannot say anything more than that.

Comment: You mean $-f(1)$, not $f(-1)$?

Comment: Sub in $-1$ you get $f(-1)=-f(-1)$ as well.

Comment: Ah, of course... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Had you used limits of integration, you would have noticed the difference. The integration constant won't be the same, would it?

Comment: That doesn't explain the indefinite integral. If $I=-I$, that means (really) that $I=-(I+C)$, which means $I$ is a constant, which can't happen, either.

Comment: @CarlHeckman The step $I=-I$ is itself wrong. And it follows from my argument. As you can see from cr001's answer. There are certain consequences of $t=\frac{1}{x}$ which he has assumed to be true to get this dubious result.